# How to adapt JSON.Parser for NaN in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to adapt JSON.Parse() for NaN.

```
console.log(JSON.parse('{"n": 1}'));
console.log(JSON.parse('{"n": NaN}'));
```

1st one is {n:1}.

2nd one has an error which says `Unexpected token N in JSON`.
And I want to change NaN to `0` like `{n: 0}`.

I found a resource which create JSON Parser from scratch.
https://lihautan.com/json-parser-with-javascript/#implementing-the-parser

It's good he separates keys and values so that I can check only values if there is NaN and fix it.
But the problem is I have no idea where I can put the NaNParser() and the process. Because the parameter looks coming 1 by 1 character.

If you could give me some advice, it really helps me.
https://codesandbox.io/s/json-parser-with-error-handling-hjwxk?from-embed

Comment: Why not iterate the string and replace `"NaN"` with `0`. Then you wouln't have to create a new JSON parser.

Comment: Do you create the JSON or is it created by another source which you don't have control over?

Comment: I do not think `NaN` is a valid value in JSON

Comment: My json is about 50MB big. So I want only check values not including the keys when fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have no idea where I can put the NaNParser() and the process.

There is `parseValue` function in that `fakeParseJSON` by Tan Li Hau you are using in your code sandbox. Teaching it to recognize `NaN` seems to be as easy as adding one `parseKeyword` call in there:

```
parseKeyword("NaN", NaN)
```

or, since you

> And I want to change NaN to 0

```
parseKeyword("NaN", 0)
```

[See fork.](https://codesandbox.io/s/json-parser-with-error-handling-forked-r2yyw5?file=/src/index.js:1490-1524)

Answer (score 2):

**Context**

Note that `JSON.stringify({"n": NaN})` outputs: `'{"n":null}'`

That means:

- `NaN` is not a valid serialised value.
- by default it is converted to `null` not `0` (because it's not a number)

**Solution**

Perhaps the fastest approach is to simply replace all NaN values before parsing it.

```
const input = '{"o": 1, "n": NaN, "m": "test"}'

const output = input.replace(/(:\s*)NaN(\s*[,}])/, '$1null$2')

console.log(output) // prints: '{"o": 1, "n": null, "m": "test"}'
```

Alternatively you could use `sed` in the terminal:

```bash
sed -e "s/pattern/replacement/g" <input.txt >output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it. But I'm looking the way to loop only the values and fix it without keys. Because my json will be 50MB or something.

Comment: I see. As long as you can't parse it, you can not iterate it in JavaScript. So a parser that looks for a specific character sequence could work.

Answer (score 1):

"Hacky" solution:

```js
var json = '{"n": NaN}';

var object = JSON.parse(json.replace("NaN", "\"NaN\""));
for(var key in object)
{
    if(object[key] == "NaN")
    {
        object[key] = NaN;
    }
}

console.log(object);
```

This replaces all NaN values in the JSON with the string "NaN", then runs that through JSON.parse, and then re-replaces all "NaN" string in the object with actual NaN.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to produce JSON with zero values in places where NaN were in the source, you can use quite simple serializer ("replacer") during native [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```js
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(
    // source data:
    {
      a: 1,
      b: NaN
    },
    // "replacer":
    function(key, value) {
      if (Number.isNaN(value)) {
        return 0
      }
      return value
    },
    // optional, indent character for formatting:
    "\t"
  )
)
```

To preserve `NaN` values, you'd have to provide custom replacer that will produce some unique structure representing it in syntactically valid JSON string, and use adequate "reviver" while doing [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#using_the_reviver_parameter) to retrieve it back:

```js
var original_data = {
    a: 1,
    NaN: NaN,
    NaNaNaNa: {
        Batman: true,
        baNaNa: NaN,
    }
}
const extra_type_value_key = "__value__";
const NaN_signal = "NaN, dude";
const NaN_representation = { [extra_type_value_key]: NaN_signal };
function replacer(key, value) {
    if (Number.isNaN(value)) {
        return NaN_representation;
    }
    return value
}
const data_JSON_string = JSON.stringify(original_data, replacer, "\t");
console.log("Data as JSON string:", data_JSON_string);
function reviver(key, value) {
    if (value && value[extra_type_value_key] && value[extra_type_value_key] === NaN_signal) {
        return NaN
    }
    return value
}
const data_POJO = JSON.parse(data_JSON_string, reviver, "\t");
console.log("Object from JSON string, should be same as original_data", data_POJO);
// unrelated
onload=()=>{with(document.querySelector('div').style)top=0,maxHeight='none'}
```

Also, for similar purpose, using dark practice of evil `eval` of JSON-like string would work:

```js
var original_data_string = `{
  a: 1,
  b: NaN,
  NaNaNa: {
    Batman: NaN,
    baNaNa: 3,
    NaN: 4
  }
}`;

var data_object = eval(`(${original_data_string})`);

console.log(data_object);
```

---

For god's sake, don't do regexp replaces on JSON source strings, especially if you do not know the shape of the data!